# Convert JSON-String to proper Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I spend 3 hours debugging, but I don't get the rootcause.

I have text (in JSON Format) in a variable. I convert it with "Convert-From-JSON" to an actual object. I was hoping that I can then work with the properties of the object. But it does not work :( It seems that the conversion only gives me two tables (status and data). What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
$results = {
  "status": "FINISHED",
  "data": {
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "11565C230500",
        "custom": {
          "image": "XXXX",
          "name": "XXXX",
          "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "22739L5F16243",
        "custom": {
          "image": "XXXX",
          "name": "XXXX",
          "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3304332724004",
        "custom": {
          "image": "XXXX",
          "name": "XXXX",
          "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
        }
      }
    ]
   }
 }
```

Now putting it as Object:

```
$resultObject = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $result
```

Now trying to retrieve:

```
$resultObject.id | where {$_.id -eq '11565C230500'}
```

Comment: The JSON you've posted is invalid (array literal following `"results":` is never closed, neither is the surrounding object)

Comment: the data posted by you is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, you define `$results` as script block where it should be a **string**:

```
$results =  @'
{
    "status": "FINISHED",
    "data": {
        "results": [{
                "id": "11565C230500",
                "custom": {
                    "image": "XXXX",
                    "name": "XXXX",
                    "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "22739L5F16243",
                "custom": {
                    "image": "XXXX",
                    "name": "XXXX",
                    "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3304332724004",
                "custom": {
                    "image": "XXXX",
                    "name": "XXXX",
                    "articleNumber": "4032423423505"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
'@
```

Now you can convert it from the JSON string

```
$resultObject = $results | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then, to parse out the nested property, you need to follow the data structure:

```
$resultObject.data.results | Where-Object {$_.id -eq '11565C230500'}
```

will give you this:

```
id           custom                                               
--           ------                                               
11565C230500 @{image=XXXX; name=XXXX; articleNumber=4032423423505}
```

If you want to get the articleNumber from the `custom` **object** that contains, dig deeper still:

```
($resultObject.data.results | Where-Object {$_.id -eq '11565C230500'}).custom.articleNumber
```

which will return `4032423423505`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the json is single quoted in that example, otherwise it's a scriptblock, and "$results" is used in place of "$result", the id property is underneath data.results.  You couldn't examine the id property with where-object if you already expanded it.  That's an alternate form of where-object.  I'm expanding the "custom" property with the foreach-object alias "%".  Note one id number is shorter.  Beware convertto-json's default depth of 2.

```
$results = '{"status":"FINISHED","data":{"results":[
{"id":"11565C230500", "custom":{"image":"XXXX","name":"XXXX","articleNumber":"4032423423505"}},
{"id":"22739L5F16243","custom":{"image":"XXXX","name":"XXXX","articleNumber":"4032423423505"}},
{"id":"3304332724004","custom":{"image":"XXXX","name":"XXXX","articleNumber":"4032423423505"}}
]}}'

$resultObject = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $results
$resultObject.data.results | where id -eq 11565C230500

id           custom
--           ------
11565C230500 @{image=XXXX; name=XXXX; articleNumber=4032423423505}


$resultobject.data.results | where id -eq 11565C230500 | % custom

image name articleNumber
----- ---- -------------
XXXX  XXXX 4032423423505
```